# re installing ros

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How should I re-install my whole ros environment?
thanks,
vahid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28823/re-installing-ros/) by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-29**:
Please be more specific. What OS are you using? What version of ROS? Why do you need to reinstall? Are you using a source-based install, or binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

actually i messed up my ros environment so I just re-install everything. thank you.

---

Originally posted by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) with karma: 31 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-29**:
i am just  curious what you really messed up which forced you to go for reinstall?